# Bypass iPad check in App Store review [iPhone only]?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I released an update for my app in App Store.It got rejected.Following was the reason:

> Binary Rejected Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness Your
> app crashed on iPad running iOS 14.1 on WiFi when we tapped on any
> notification

My app is meant for iPhone only & doesn't require iPad support.Is there any way to bypass this iPad check in review?Any way to build only for iPhone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove iPad support from AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746695/how-can-i-remove-ipad-support-from-appstore)

Answer (score 2):

Apple team installs app on iPad and test it so no matter your app supports iPad or not the app will be installed on iPad and the UI will be bigger(zoomed) if iPad support is not given to your app.

So the issue the apple review team gave you is that your app is crashing on the notification tap. So its better to test this on iPad simulator to re-product this issue and fixed it, then upload again to store.

*Note: There is no way to by pass the Apple review process. If you try to manipulate it (as the user privacy is the Apple's primary concern) your apple developer account get suspended/banned for life long.*